# Kile's structure view over multiple project files

Tags: kile

Long story short: I'ld like to extend Kile's structure view to display chapters, sections, etc. from multiple .tex files. I already added those files to the project. Unfortunately Kile only displays the structure of the file which is open in the editor right now.

Is there any setting I missed?

I'm using Kile 2.1.3 on Ubuntu 14.10 64bit.

Comment: Second that, or if there is an editor with this freature?